# problemas al quitar paquete de node_modules

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework

Tengo un proyecto en Ionic-framework. Instalé el paquete de @capacitor/geolocation, pero este está teniendo problemas en la geolocalización con las últimas versiones de android.
Bueno, los sustituí por @ionic-native/geolocation. Eliminé mi servicio de geolocalización en capacitor. Quité cualquier referencia al servicio. Hice otro servicio para trabajar con native y funciona bien. Sin embargo, cuando compilo y abro el Android Studio, este me sigue pidiendo @capacitor/geolocation.

Esto me muestra AS:

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :capacitor-geolocation.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > No matching configuration of project :capacitor-geolocation was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' but:
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Este es mi package.json:

```
{
  "name": "taxi",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "3.2.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.2.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "3.2.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/storage": "^1.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "@ionic/cli": "^6.17.0",
    "@types/ol": "^6.5.3",
    "@types/openlayers": "^4.6.18",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ol": "^6.6.1",
    "ol-ext": "^3.2.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "types-ol-ext": "^1.0.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.10",
    "@types/arcgis-rest-api": "^10.4.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

No comprendo, ¿por qué me sigue pidiendo ese paquete? Igual me sucedió con Background Geolocation tiempo atrás en otro proyecto y tuve que comenzar una nueva app; pero quiero quitar el error porque esta está muy avanzada.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score -1):

Sorry pals. Al parecer publicar acá me ayuda para encontrar los errores.
Resolví el problema quitando la referencia en capacitor.build.gradle.
Yo pensé que eso se quitaba solo al desintalar el plugin.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Digamos que tu escenario no era reproducible no?

Comment: .\android\app\capacitor.build.gradle

Editar este archivo y de las dependencias quitar cualquier referencia al plugins desinstalado:

dependencies {
    implementation project(':capacitor-app')
    implementation project(':capacitor-haptics')
    implementation project(':capacitor-keyboard')
    implementation project(':capacitor-status-bar')
    implementation project(':capacitor-storage')

}

Comment: Eso tiene que estar en la respuesta.. que para eso esta.. no hay que andar indagando en los comentarios para tener la respuesta completa.. no?

Comment: Lo siento pal. Para la próxima.

Comment: no... porque para la proxima?? hay un boton [edit] que te permite modificar todo lo que haces... lo que te llevo ese comentario, era el tiempo que tardabas en editar....